# Flash-php data transfer. How exactly it works?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-2

guys!

I searched a lot, but at least I come here to ask you for an explanation of that.

It's not exactly that, but it works the same way. It's about a login form with Flash and PHP. It must send data (username and password) to PHP, PHP has to check for a record in MySQL and then to return data to Flash. How does it works and how to return the data to Flash?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're talking about Flash remoting, then you'll want [AMFPHP](http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/)

Comment: I need a very simple function, and, as I understood AMFPHP is kinda framework.

Comment: Not really. AMF is Flash's native client/server communications form, and AMFPHP is a php implementation of the server-side of it.

Comment: OK, fine. But I know how to do the server-side, and I think, that I will format them, right, to be used inn Flash, but I actually, don't know how to use them in AS2, when they ae returned from php.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC this was possible with `loadVars()` in Flash 2 and 3. http://www.peterelst.com/blog/2007/11/28/actionscript-30-wheres-my-loadvars/

Comment: It's in as3, and I'm using as2